# How to select a JSON object from Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase structure]

I have a Firebase structure like below. I want to get the message as a returned object. To do this in SQL like

```
select messages from HukMesssage
```

How can I do that?

Can anyone helps me how to change the SQL to Firebase query?

My json file looks like below

```
{
    "HukMessages":
        [
            {
                "To": 1,
                "From": 2,
                "messages": [
                        {
                          "name": "'Venkman'",
                          "message": "'You on your way?'",
                          "face": "'img/venkman.jpg'"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "name": "'Felix He'",
                          "message": "'Ionic comes with a set of colors to start with, but as a general rule colors are meant to be overridden. '",
                          "face": "'img/felix.jpg'"
                        }
                ]
            }
           ]
}
```

Comment: I would go through the tutorial they have on their site so you can see how this is set up. There's a lot wrong with what you're doing (arrays, not using child/ref)

Comment: var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("HukMessages").orderByChild("From").equalTo('2');   this retuens HukMessages but i want messages object

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code will need to deal with the list. Something like:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref().child("HukMessages").orderByChild(‌​"From").equalTo('2')‌​; 
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key); // this will print HukMessages, because that's the location you queried

  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log(child.key); // this will print the key of a message
  });
});
```